# GE Water Softener: Can it function without the outflow turbine that monitors water flow going out?

Tags: water-softener

I just replaced the resin in my water softener which went find and dandy, but while reassembling the unit to the plumbing (in-flow / out-flow), I accidentally put the water flow turbine in backwards and broke it. The Turbine is the little plastic fan piece that rotates a magnet so a sensor can monitor outflow.

My question is: Is this an essential piece to replace? if my water softener recharges every night, can I assume that this sensor is only for troubleshooting and monitoring, thus I can live without it?

For reference, this is [my water softener's manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/748183/Morton-System-Saver-Msd20f.html?term=schedule&selected=4&page=24#manual). This page shows a little picture of the turbine on the bottom right corner of that page of the manual.

Comment: I've used softenerparts.com but when searched, your specific part number lists as "currently unavailable" and no other sites appear on a general search. I have that part as a refrigerator magnet, after taking apart a discarded softener. There's no method on SE for individual contact. I'd be happy to toss it in an envelope and send it off to you. Suggestions?

Comment: Just to be certain, your softener recharges daily and does _not_ recharge based on usage? If that's the case, you can _probably_ live without it, though it may shorten the softeners overall life. I'd suggest ordering the replacement part and installing it much sooner rather than later, but that you'll be OK until then. If the softener monitors water usage to determine when to recharge, you'll run out of soft water and have to manually kick off a recharge. All this also depends on whether water is leaking with that turbine missing - that could cause issues based on where the water ends up.

Comment: @fred_dot_u Exactly. I wasn't able to find it on any major ecommerce site online and thought to ask SE if it was even strictly necessary. I suppose that part would make an interesting fridge magnet. Since Stack Exchange is a forum,  [they don't offer private messaging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213396/how-can-i-send-a-private-message-to-someone-on-stack-overflow) so that would get tricky finding a way to make contact, unfortunately, but man I appreciate that offer a great deal, brother.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for the insight. I'll keep an eye out for leaks. Nothing so far. So far so good without it. For now, I'll keep hunting to find a replacement (from who knows where at this point).

Comment: @MarkWitmer, if you still want to pursue a contact, I have no objections. My username is on the 3dprintboard.com web site and they have direct messaging. Send an address and I'll have it in the post tout de suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your softener should be set on gallons.
it is a real waste of water and salt to automatically regenerate every night.

If you don’t care it probably will be fine but when properly set up it may not need to regenerate even 1/2 as often as you are.

But if you are happy with a 24 hour regenerate it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I'll have to read the manual a bit more to see how that's done. That's a great point. It had been set on a daily schedule since I moved in. This could explain the reason it needed maintenance this soon. I appreciate you taking the time to answer. I've made it the accepted answer.

Comment: [Based on this page in the manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/748183/Morton-System-Saver-Msd20f.html?page=13#manual), it appears daily regeneration is the only option, but there is some type of efficiency setting on the very next page that would require that turbine.

Comment: Wow all the ones I have experience with have had time bases or gallons, the time based can be an advantage so it is set when water is not normally being used.

Comment: It does pain me to know it's extremely inefficient. On the bright side, fixing it DIY has been extremely cost effective. I guess it is what it is (daily regenerations).

Comment: @EdBeal The ones I’ve had are both gallon and time based. The regen is triggered after the specified flow but the regen then waits until the middle of the night. Best of both.